# Access config global in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, service-locator

I would like to access to my global configs (`config/{,*.}{global,local}.php`) located in my personal libraries (in the `vendor` directory).
But despite my search in the web, I did not succeed to achieve this.

I know how to access the config file of a module :

```
\MyModule\Module::getConfig()
```

I know how to access the global configurations from a controller :

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
```

But how to access these from a file inside the vendor directory ?
My libraries do not extend anything, it may be the root of the problem ?
Can I use a static method to access these ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you access the reader in the Config factory trough the Zend\\ namespace? But isn't the vendor suppose to to be seperated from Zend pattern wise? Can't you just add/overwrite the modules config?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. Indeed, you are right, I shouldn't try to use zend config files in my vendor directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it through the serviceManager.
In controller:

```
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
```

Otherwise same way, just you need service Manager, for eaxmple in Module.php:

```
  public function getConfig()
  {
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
  }

  public function getServiceConfig()
  {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'mail.transport' =>  function($sm) {
                $config = $sm->get('Config');

                 switch($config['mail']['transport']['type']){
                ..................
```

Answer (score 0):

easy way to do this. not only in module but anywhere.

```
$config = new \Zend\Config\Config( include APPLICATION_PATH.'/config/autoload/global.php' ); 

echo $config->myconfig;
```

define `APPLICATION_PATH` in public/index.php